# How to detect if the device (iphone) has physical home button?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How to detect in **Swift** if the current device (iPhone) has a physical home button or hasn't, like: **iPhone X, iPhone Xs, iPhone Xs Max, iPhone Xr** ?

Comment: No home button == safe area > 0 returns true

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you wish to know if a device has a Home button or not?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model - maybe modify the extension to deal with the devices you're concerned about.

Comment: This question shows how to tell what authentication a device supports, but again why? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46887547/how-to-programatically-check-support-of-face-id-and-touch-id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: Detect if the device is iPhone X family (frameless)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52402477/ios-detect-if-the-device-is-iphone-x-family-frameless)

Comment: @rmaddy, I wanted to design custom tab bar, but the iPhone X family devices have different tab bar style. I should ask about the iPhone X family devices, not about the physical home button XD

Comment: What's different about the tab bar style? It looks the same to me as any other device.

Comment: @rmaddy the height for example

Comment: That extra height is from the safe area. So you don't need to know the type of device. Just add the safe area.

Comment: @rmaddy you're totally right, I didn't ask the right question, thanks anyway

Comment: Which was the point of my original comment. In most cases, when someone is looking to detect a specific device (or device type), they are doing it wrong. It's always best to focus a question on the actual task you are trying to solve.

Comment: this question is perfectly valid. In my case, it's because we want to indicate to less savvy users how to access the control panel (with a caveat that this could change over time and therefore not show it for future iOS version we don't know about.)

Comment: This question (and the answer!) was useful to me. Here's why I need to know: I want to emulate how the device Lock Screen looks and I need to know whether iOS will display "Press home to open" at the bottom or not. If there's a physical home button it does that, else not.

Comment: I'm afraid the "why" comments here are misguided. It is 100% normal that you need to adjust layouts depending on whether the "push-up bar" is there or not.  One example of dozens is when you have a rounded element. Note, *Apple do this* in a number of their apps!  By all means, devs should understand to "just use the safe area" where that is relevant, but you have to determine buttonless/notchy in almost all designs.

Comment: Err, for a couple more years, until the ancient phones get lost!  :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Check the safe area:

```
if @available(iOS 11.0, *), 
    UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom > 0 {
    return true
}
return false
```

Swift 4.2 version:-

```
var isBottom: Bool {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *), let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow, keyWindow.safeAreaInsets.bottom > 0 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

You can also check the device type (check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model)), but checking the safe area is probably the easiest way.

Comment: Swift 4.2: ```if #available(iOS 11.0, *), let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow, keyWindow.safeAreaInsets.bottom > 0 {
                
            return true
        }
        
        return false```

Comment: I need to know whether the button exists very early as my layout depends on it, but at the time I query it keyWindow is null. Are there any other ways to find out about the buttons existence?

Answer (score 5):

For iOS 13 and higher:

```
    var isBottom: Bool {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *), UIApplication.shared.windows[0].safeAreaInsets.bottom > 0 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Iphones which have hardware home buttons can have iOS >= 13 installed, so I believe this is not correct.

Answer (score -1):

**iOS version >= 13.0**

*UIApplication.shared.windows* is deprecated from **iOS 15.0**, we can replace it like below:

```
    var hasHomeButton: Bool {
        let window = UIApplication
            .shared
            .connectedScenes
            .compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }
            .flatMap { $0.windows }
            .first { $0.isKeyWindow }
        guard let safeAreaBottom =  window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom else {
            return false
        }
        return safeAreaBottom <= 0
    }
```

*In **SwiftUI** you can also use this variable, but don't use it from `init()` of your SwiftUI view struct.*