# how to determine whether the ios device is a face or a touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, touch-id, face-id

when I turn off face id on the setting，I get a error as follow：

```
    LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
    NSError *authError = nil;
    [myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]
```

authError is "No identities are enrolled."
This error does not indicate whether the phone is touch id or face id，how I determine whether the ios device is a face or a touch？

I have tried differnt iphone device，authError is "No identities are enrolled.". I can not determine whether the ios device is a face or a touch.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/2867583-biometrytype

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically check support of 'Face Id' and 'Touch Id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46887547/how-to-programmatically-check-support-of-face-id-and-touch-id)

Answer (score 0):

The [`biometryType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/2867583-biometrytype?language=objc) property of the `LAContext` object tells you what type of biometric authentication is available on the current device:

```
LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
switch (myContext.biometryType) {
    case LABiometryTypeFaceID:
        // Do something with Face ID
    break;

    case LABiometryTypeTouchId:
       // Do something with Touch ID
    break;

    case LABiometryTypeNone:
       // Biometrics are not available
}
```